# Magento + Amazon Payments and Fulfilment - How to handle Prime Customers

Tags: magento, amazon-pay

Using Magento CE and will be integrating both Amazon Payments for checkout and Amazon Fullfilment.

Amazon provides their 'Pay with Amazon' Magento extension, and there are a few extension out there for fullfilment (including inventory sync).

What I'm having a hard time finding any info on, is regarding how to handle Amazon Prime. Both the display of Prime eligible on the eligible products and ensuring that prime customers receive the appropriate shipping fullfilment time (and show that on the shopping cart, and pass the data through to Amazon appropriately).

Neither the Amazon Payment extension, or the few Amazon fulfilment extension found mention the management of Prime products and customers (and not getting responses from inquiries).

Any information towards the above would be extremely helpful in helping to determine the level of effort to implement (as that needs to be determined before the integration project is approved).

Comment: Could be very wrong, but IINM, Prime is for the Amazon platform -meaning you have products selling _at_ Amazon platform(?), not  your own site/app.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Amazon Fulfillment goes along with the products on their platform (and they have methods to connect your own store CMS and use Amazon to populate your site product database and maintain a sync).

Comment: Is this question programming related?

Answer (score 0):

Login with Amazon does not disclose Prime membership status so this is currently impossible to do. It may become a feature at some point but there are no plans to do so currently.